# How to run the simple SharpDevelop DirectX Framework in Visual C# 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, directx, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm following **Ron Penton's Beggining C# Game Programming** book and in Part 2 it begins with DirectX programming. To start, it tells me to generate the code from the SharpDevelop's wizard then copy both AssemblyInfo.cs and MainClass.cs generated-files to the Visual C# project's folder.

After that, it tells me to add the following references to my Visual C# project: `System.dll, System.Drawing.dll, System.Windows.Forms.dll, Microsoft.DirectX, and Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D modules`. I found the directX modules in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET` folder then added.

The sample programam compiled in SharpDevelop and my 640x420 blank window appeared. But, when I compile in Visual C# I get this error: [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABzQZ.jpg)

Since I'm new at C# programming. I don't know what this could be. I know that I didn't skipped any step in my book, I think that it's an updated version which needs some extra code.

Comment: This book is 6 years old (October of 2004). I would suggest getting a newer book that targets XNA as that is now the platform of choice for .Net game development.

Comment: Strongly disagree. XNA is only the "platform of choice" for WP7 and hobbyists who want to write games which will work on Xbox360 with minimal hassle.

Comment: In both instances, also only the platform of choice due to artificial restrictions on better alternatives.

Comment: @FerretallicA: From Wikipedia MDX (Managed DirectX) is currently deprecated in favour of XNA Game Studio Express. I find it hard to believe that anyone choosing to develop games using .Net will find a better alternative than XNA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to refer to an older library that is not supported by Visual Studio 2010.

VS2010 supports .NET v2.0 or later while the one you're trying to use is v1.1.

A quick solution is to try locate Visual Studio 2003 and use it, or you can start embracing the future by using XNA.

Comment: I tought that following the book would be a good start, since it explains 2D and 3D programming. I just didn't know that it was that old. I'll try to get a newer book with XNA

Comment: BTW, the 2D programming (at least) is easy to understand in this book. Does XNA game development become more complex? I've never manipulated graphics, just the console applications